# Installing Swift3 without xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, swift3, installation, homebrew

Is it possible to use apple's swift3 without xcode at all. I want to experiment with the language and for my needs the terminal version would suffice.

I'm on a macOS, which came preinstalled with swift2

Comment: Yes. Everything is explained at https://swift.org/.

Comment: @EricAya Mmm, not really. They *always* lead to the Xcode download page eventually.

Comment: The page is confusing. The link for installing the Swift compiler without Xcode is there, but tiny, and right under the Xcode one. Have a look at my [screenshot](https://monosnap.com/file/95OGJ3hoxawRzVOdhEYtYgDdtreMmY). :)

Comment: Gee thanks! I did try it before but cancelled the download - I thought there was no way a language installation could be that huge ;)